# how to create center of div popup vertical and horizental css html

Tags: html, css

[image: horizental image]

[image: vertical image]

i want to create horizental and vertical div .

center of div popup outside like above images

and show arrow point to out side of text without bootstrap

[image]

Comment: Where is your tried code?

Comment: where is your code? all i see is images. show what you have tried, and explain in detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i have understand your questions i am trying to give you few suggestions as below:

For horizontal align you can simply give you popup div a width in px or % or any unit and add margin:0px auto;. if you are using position:absolute then give width and right:0px; left:0px; it will align horizontal your div.

For Vertical align you can either use line-height which should be same as height of your div.

or also you can use display:table; to parent div and for child div add display:table-cell & vertical-align:middle;

Hope it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Generally you can just use absolute positioning, [like](https://jsfiddle.net/zsvaz03n/):

```
.foo {    
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: -50px 0 0 -50px;
  background: lightblue; //not necessary of course
}
```

This way it will end in the middle of the screen (with some limitations ;)).

Another option is to use flex-box, but I would downvote it because of flex-box performance.

If you need to position it inside another div, yet absolutely centered, it will go quite similar, yet parent element has to have absolute positioning as well, in order for child element to get it right.